# Detecting changes in a web page's content

Tags: diff, web-crawler

I'm looking for an approach (not a library or framework, as I can't seem to find one) to detecting changes in a web pages content. I've taken a look at posts similar to [Tracking changes to web page content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612668/tracking-changes-to-web-page-content), and white papers (http://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/2415/14/14_chapter%205.pdf), but having trouble figuring out a good approach.

I don't believe an md5 of a page's content is useful, as the content of most pages change slightly depending on when you request it (eg. if they hardcode the day's date).

Additionally, I'd like to figure out a way to determine what content has actually changed (eg. running a diff on the content that is seen as different is good enough, but I would first need to figure out which content is different).

http://www.changedetection.com/ seems to do a solid job of this.
Any approaches or ideas or links would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you end up figuring out a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP Last-Modified and [ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) headers may be a way to go. However, if the web pages you crawl do not implement them, you are left with text similarity detection.